# How to unversion just a variable?

Tags: mercurial

If I want some part even inside a file to not be versioned i.e. like a password or likewise, is there a way to tell mercurial to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You would have to move the stuff you don't want versioned into a separate file. Then just don't track that file in the repo.

How you accomplish that depends on your development stack. If it is a project that is compiled, including it as an embedded resource allows you to compile it in and retrieve the value at runtime. Doing some sort of `include` of the separate file is another option.